# Not getting data from drop down's from backend file

Tags: html, asp.net, backend

I have been trying to figure out the issue with my backend script for a day now and it has been a bit frustrating. Basically, the backend script is not grabbing the data from the dropdowns on my webpage. It can register when the button is pressed and can save to the SQL database but it won't grab the data inside the dropdowns. Like "Department 1" etc.. I have tried a couple methods but it seems to always be blank.

I have a button and two drop downs on a webpage that are initiated by:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
                <label for="department">Department:<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="departmentDropDown" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" required></asp:DropDownList>

                <label for="partNumber">Part Number:<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="partNumberDropDown" runat="server" required></asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton" Text="Click me" OnClick="myButton_Click" />
            </form>
```

And I have a backend of:

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get selected values from dropdowns
        string selectedDepartment = departmentDropDown.SelectedValue;
        string selectedPartNumber = partNumberDropDown.SelectedValue;

        // Write the selected values to the response
        Response.Write("Selected Department:" +  selectedDepartment + "<br/>");
        Response.Write("sent by:" +  sender + "<br/>");
        Response.Write("sent by:" +  sender + "<br/>");
        Response.Write("Selected Part Number: "+ selectedPartNumber+ "<br/>");


        Response.Write("<br/> NOT SAVED!");
    }
```

I have been trying a couple different response's from the backend to see what's going on, but it seems to always do the same thing. I would love to make this work!

How I populate the dropdowns currently:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
        }
        PopulateDepartmentDropdown();
        PopulatePartNumberDropdown();
    }

    private void PopulateDepartmentDropdown()
    {
        // Replace this with your logic to fetch department data from a data source
        DataTable departmentData = GetStaticDepartmentsData();
        //DataTable departmentData = GetDepartmentsData();

        // Clear existing items in the dropdown
        departmentDropDown.Items.Clear();

        // Add an initial blank item if needed
        departmentDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("-- Select Department --", ""));

        // Add items to the dropdown from the DataTable
        foreach (DataRow row in departmentData.Rows)
        {
            // Assuming that 'DepartmentIDColumn' and 'DepartmentNameColumn' are column names in your DataTable
            string departmentID = row["department"].ToString();
            string departmentName = row["department"].ToString();

            departmentDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(departmentName, departmentID));
        }
    }

    private void PopulatePartNumberDropdown()
    {
        // Replace this with your logic to fetch part number data from a data source
        //DataTable partNumberData = GetPartNumbersData();
        DataTable partNumberData = GetStaticPartNumbersData();

        // Clear existing items in the dropdown
        partNumberDropDown.Items.Clear();

        // Add an initial blank item if needed
        partNumberDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("-- Select Part Number --", ""));

        // Add items to the dropdown from the DataTable
        foreach (DataRow row in partNumberData.Rows)
        {
            // Assuming that 'PartNumberIDColumn' and 'PartNumberNameColumn' are column names in your DataTable
            string partNumberID = row["partnumbers"].ToString();
            string partNumberName = row["partnumbers"].ToString();

            partNumberDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(partNumberName, partNumberID));
        }
    }
    private DataTable GetStaticDepartmentsData()
    {
        DataTable departmentsData = new DataTable();
        departmentsData.Columns.Add("department");

        // Add static department data
        departmentsData.Rows.Add("DepartmentA");
        departmentsData.Rows.Add("DepartmentB");
        departmentsData.Rows.Add("DepartmentC");

        return departmentsData;
    }
    
    private DataTable GetStaticPartNumbersData()
    {
        DataTable partNumbersData = new DataTable();
        partNumbersData.Columns.Add("partnumbers");

        // Add static part number data
        partNumbersData.Rows.Add("12345");
        partNumbersData.Rows.Add("67890");
        partNumbersData.Rows.Add("ABCDE");

        return partNumbersData;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you populate those drop-downs with data?  Are you doing that in `Page_Load`?  Are you doing that unconditionally, and thereby clobbering the value during a post-back?

Comment: My guess would be that you fill data to the dropdown without an IsPostBack check.

Comment: I just added the populating scripts. They are static for now.

Comment: Put `PopulateDepartmentDropdown()` and `PopulatePartNumberDropdown()` inside the `if (IsPostBack)`

Comment: I just did, it wont populate the dropdowns anymore. Is there something else I am supposed to do?

Comment: @Finlay: There's likely an appropriate duplicate question that I'm not finding, but re-populating drop-down lists on `Page_Load` unconditionally would indeed clobber the posted value.  Those should only be conditionally populated.  The most common condition is simply checking `IsPostBack`, though it's certainly possible that your setup is more complex than that.  When you debug, what happens when you load the page?  Are those methods for populating the drop-downs invoked on the initial page load?

Comment: The dropdowns should be populated during initial pageload, not each time to you postback. Once you postback, you were repopulating the dropdowns and in doing so, you were clearing their items and then repopulating which would remove the item you had selected. Instead of looping over the datatable, why not assign it to the `datasource` property of the dropdown and then call its `databind()` method? Also, you should be able to turn off the `EnableViewState` property on your dropdowns in the markup.

Comment: So I am not experienced with backend development. I have not done something like this before. I am not sure how to put it in debug mode. I am developing this from a work computer that is external to the server and using Visual Studio Code to make it. I can understand that I need to call it inside the IsPostBack, but it will not populate the dropdowns anymore when I do.

Comment: In your aspx markup, set `EnableViewState = false` or remove it altogether.

Comment: No apparent change sadly.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console? I see the word `required` inside of your dropdown list declarations which may be throwing an exception

Comment: No messages/errors. I have removed the required part and tried that. No apparent change. Is there a class or something I need to reference?

Comment: @Finlay: We can appreciate the struggle, but if you're not at all able to use a debugger than that is the first problem to be solved, as debugging is an *essential* part of software development.  You might try a free version of Visual Studio, or look into debugging a WebForms application in VS Code.

Comment: Your issue after moving the code is you were likely checking for `isPostBack = true` instead of `IsPostback = false` so you were not populating the dropdowns on initial page load and instead would be populating them each postback. Answer below with some other comments.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much for your help. I changed it to !IsPostBack and then it populated and returned the values inside the dropdowns.

Comment: Take a few minutes to look through the whole answer below. You can greatly simply your databinding since you are already working with a datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some strangeness in your markup which has been cleaned up. The dropdown with the `EnableViewState = "true"` has had that removed as it isn't needed here. There were also several places where the work `required` were just inside of your asp tags. This may be valid however I've never seen it before and could not find reference for it in short time. Lastly, as a matter of personal preference, if you are not writing inside of the tags, make them self closing for easier reading.

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <label for="department">Department:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="departmentDropDown" runat="server" />

    <label for="partNumber">Part Number:<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="partNumberDropDown" runat="server" />

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton" Text="Click me" OnClick="myButton_Click" />
</form>
```

Your Page_load is doing the write things the wrong way. Instead of checking for `isPostback = true` you need `isPostBack = false` because we are looking for the initial page load. I have also cleaned up how you were databinding your controls a bit. You do not need to loop over the datatable. Simply assign it, set the text/value fields, and call databind as you see below.

A point worth noting, when building a temporary data source, keep it consistent to the format you expect from your main data source. I adjusted the column names and added a column to your datatables you are creating based on your comments in the appropriate methods. This can be adjusted if that is not what your columns are named.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            //do postback logic here
        } else {
            // do initial page load logic here
            PopulateDepartmentDropdown();
            PopulatePartNumberDropdown();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateDepartmentDropdown()
    {
        // Replace this with your logic to fetch department data from a data source
        DataTable departmentData = GetStaticDepartmentsData();
        //DataTable departmentData = GetDepartmentsData();

        departmentDropDown.Items.Clear(); // Clear existing items in the dropdown

        departmentDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("-- Select Department --", "")); // Add an initial blank item if needed

            // Assuming that 'DepartmentID' and 'DepartmentName' are column names in your DataTable
            departmentDropDown.DataValueField = "departmentID";
            departmentDropdown.DataTextField = "departmentName";
            departmentDropdown.DataSource = departmentData;
            departmentDropdown.DataBind();
    }

    private void PopulatePartNumberDropdown()
    {
        // Replace this with your logic to fetch part number data from a data source
        //DataTable partNumberData = GetPartNumbersData();
        DataTable partNumberData = GetStaticPartNumbersData();

        partNumberDropDown.Items.Clear(); // Clear existing items in the dropdown

        partNumberDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("-- Select Part Number --", "")); // Add an initial blank item

            // Assuming that 'PartNumberID' and 'PartNumberName' are column names in your DataTable
        partNumberDropDown.DataSource = partNumberData;
        partNumberDropDown.DataTextField = "partNumberName";
        partNumberDropDown.DataValueField = "partNumberID";
        partNumberDropDown.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable GetStaticDepartmentsData()
    {
        DataTable departmentsData = new DataTable();
        departmentsData.Columns.Add("departmentID");
        departmentsData.Columns.Add("departmentName");

        // Add static department data
        departmentsData.Rows.Add("DepartmentA","DepartmentA");
        departmentsData.Rows.Add("DepartmentB","DepartmentB");
        departmentsData.Rows.Add("DepartmentC","DepartmentC");

        return departmentsData;
    }
    
    private DataTable GetStaticPartNumbersData()
    {
        DataTable partNumbersData = new DataTable();
        partNumbersData.Columns.Add("partNumberID");
        partNumbersData.Columns.Add("partNumberName");

        // Add static part number data
        partNumbersData.Rows.Add("12345","12345");
        partNumbersData.Rows.Add("67890","67890");
        partNumbersData.Rows.Add("ABCDE","ABCDE");

        return partNumbersData;
    }
```